# Why does putting 470 Ω at the base of the transistor turn the LED on, while putting 100 kΩ at the base turns the LED off?

Tags: transistors, amplifier

When I put 100 kΩ at the base the LED is off, but when I put 470 Ω the LED is on and it's even brighter than when I remove the resistor at the base.

Why is this happening?

[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fl4uLm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here's the actual circuit. The transistor is a BC548.

[image]

Comment: Your circuit is not correct. I would guess that with the 470 Ohm resistor it is passing the current to the led.  Why is the led in parallel with the transistor?

Comment: If the circuit is really as drawn, with a 100K resistor in series with the LED and transistor, I'd be surprised if the LED shows any detectable light.

Comment: @Kartman you mean the current from the base is passed onto the led when it's 470 ohms?

Comment: Which transistor is it? And are you absolutely sure the resistance values and diagram are correct? Can you measure voltage over battery, resiators and LED (so all transistor pin voltages and currents are known) and report the values in the diagram?

Comment: @RomerBagasis Justme is directly on-target here. There is no way your diagram is correct if the behavior you describe is accurate. Either your description is wrong or else the diagram is wrong. Which is it?

Comment: @jonk There is one possibility but I want to make sure before I suggest it. Another possibility is a broken transistor too.

Comment: @Justme Sure, there are other possibilities. With increasing remoteness, I suspect. But agreed. I'll let you work through your process and see where it comes out in the end. By the way, 2 months left before I leave this site, permanently. Best wishes to you. And thanks so much for being here. I've learned a great deal and you were an important part of that process for me. I will miss you and some others very much.

Comment: Please post a picture of your actual circuit, and provide a part number for the transistor.

Comment: @PStechPaul Ive added a picture of the actual circuit.

Comment: @jonk Thank you and I appreciate the discussions, best wishes to you too. I see my idea about Vbc breakdown was not correct as the breadboard circuit does not match the drawing. The breadboard has a resistor between emitter and ground. The emitter may still have bad connection.

Comment: I think you made a resistor parallel with 470 and 100000 Ω. That’s why it works with the 470 Ω. (LED with solely 100000 Ω will be very dim)

Comment: Yes, looks like a 470 ohm resistor from emitter to GND.

Comment: Note the BC548 is EBC whereas other transistors maybe BCE or ECB. Get the circuit and wiring correct and things will make sense.

Comment: BC548 is CBE, reverse from many TO-92 like 2N3904 that are EBC.

Answer (score 11):

You actually have implemented this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPTOqI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When R2 is 100K the current from R3 is shunted away and the voltage across D1 is lower than the Vf of the LED.

When R2 is 470Ω then the base-collector junction becomes forward biased and almost 10mA will flow through the LED.

---

When R2 is 470 ohms there is no transistor action and the behavior is similar to the below schematic (D2/D3 represent the transistor junctions). This is not a valid simulation for when R2  is 100K because there *is* transistor action in that case.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fK9ooy.png)</sup>

Comment: Is this diagram different from the one I've drawn? What does shunted away mean?

Comment: @RomerBagasis Indeed different. Please look closely.

Comment: What does shunted away mean @winny

Comment: @RomerBagasis https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunt_%28electrical%29

Comment: Why isn't the base-collector forward biased when R2 is 100K ohms?

Comment: It's slightly forward biased but the voltage across R1 is < 0.1V and the voltage at the collector of Q1 will be maybe 0.2V. With R2 = 470 ohms the voltage across R1 would like to increase to almost 4V, but the LED in conjunction with the forward biased B-C junction clamps it to the LED Vf + 1 diode junction, so a few mA flows through R1 and the rest (almost 10mA) flows through D1, causing it to light brightly.

Comment: Tbh I still don't get it. I don't get how R1 affects the forward biasing of the BC junction. I still don't get why the LED is on at 470 ohms. Could you please explain it in a way that a newbie can understand? @SpehroPefhany

Comment: There is no transistor action and the transistor acts as two forward biased diodes conducting current from base to emitter (normal) and from base to collector (not normal). The latter is what passes through the LED. You can play with the simulator using the circuit I set up above.

Answer (score 4):

The circuit is configured such that the transistor shunts current from the LED, and higher base current will reduce current and brightness of the LED. It is not a practical circuit for controlling an LED.

Here is my simulation of the actual circuit, showing LED currents for base resistors of 470 ohms, 100k, and 100 Meg (open):

[image: LED Circuit]

Comment: So why is the LED On when it's 470 ohms and off when it's 100k?

Comment: I simulated the circuit and it does not act the way you describe. If the emitter is not connected to ground, current will flow through the base-collector diode junction and will have behavior similar to what you observe.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany explained it in his answer.

Comment: You said "higher base current will reduce current  and brightness of the LED", this is exactly what I'm aiming at. But as you can see in your simulation, why is there more current passing through the LED at 470 ohms when base currents at 470 ohms is the highest of the three?

Comment: My previous comment was based on the original circuit you posted. That no longer applies.

Comment: Why does it no longer applies? Isn't the circuit that I've drawn the same as implemented?

Comment: No. You have a 470 ohm resistor from emitter to GND, which your schematics do not show,

Comment: Oh right does that affect the outcome in any way?